# Stern-Gerlach experiment need for collimated beam?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the Stern-Gerlach  why do we need a collimated beam? I read somewhere that it was to do with controlling the speed of the particle but I cannot see how collimation whould do this?

[image]

[Picture from [wikipedia](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Stern-Gerlach_experiment.PNG)]

Comment: Any angular spread in your beam will blur out the spots and maybe even make them merge so they can't be seen.

Comment: Collimation means to make a nearly parallel beam that spreads out as little as possible. When the silver atoms come out of the furnace their velocity vectors are random. The collimator plates after the surface select only those atoms that are in a narrow beam and which have almost parallel velocity vectors. In the original experiment the two beams split by a mere 0.2mm, so the beams have to be narrower than that, still!